# Need plot numerous sets of data, however I need to "shift" them so that they all have the same initial y value when t=0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

Any Ideas on how I can accomplish this? I am very new to mathematica...

My initial thoughts were to import the data from excel in .CSV and determine the max y value in all of the sets of data, and shift the rest of the initial y values to that value. Also I need to keep the time values unchanged, and it needs to work for N# of lists.

I have no Idea how to do this, or if there is a simpler solution. Thanks!

Example:

List#1-> {{8,0},{6,1},{4,2}}, List#2-> {{7,0},{6,1},{2,2}}

List#1-> {{8,0},{6,1},{4,2}}, List#2-> {{8,0},{7,1},{3,2}}

All y values in list #2 were shifted up by one.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: see `Map` , `Part` , `Maximum`

Answer (score 0):

He has asked this question at least one other place. He seems to want to add an offset to each pair in a list so that the first of the first of all the lists become the same, the first of each pair in the rest of each list have the same offset added and the second of each pair is unchanged and he wants this to work on a relatively arbitrary number of lists.

Try to adapt this and see if it works for you

```
list1 = {{8, 0}, {6, 1}, {4, 2}};
list2 = {{7, 0}, {6, 1}, {2, 2}};
list3 = {{5, 0}, {7, 1}, {5, 2}};
list4 = {{9, 0}, {4, 1}, {1, 2}};
f[v_] := Map[# + {list1[[1, 1]] - v[[1, 1]], 0} &, v];
{list2, list3, list4} = Map[f, {list2, list3, list4}]
```

which should assign {{8,0},{7,1},{3,2}} to list2, {{8,0},{10,1},{8,2}} to list3 and {{8,0},{3,1},{0,2}} to list4.